# I would like to concatenate anonymous calls in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, anonymous-function

So, I'm learning more about Julia and I would like to do the following:

I have a 3 row by 2 columns matrix, which is fixed,
`A = rand(2,3)`

```
julia> A = rand(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.705942  0.553562  0.731246
 0.205833  0.106978  0.131893
```

Then, I would like to have a anonymous function, which does the following:

```
a = ones(1,3);
a[2] = rand();
```

Finally, I would like to broadcast
`broadcast(+, ones(1,3) => a[2]=rand(), A)`

So I have the middle column of `A`, i.e., `A[:,2]`, added by two **different** random numbers, and in the rest of the columns, we add ones.

EDIT:
If I add `a`, as it is:

```
julia> a = ones(1,3)
1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0

julia> a[2] = rand()
0.664824196431979

julia> a
1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.664824  1.0
```

I would like that this `a` were dynamic, and a function.

So that:

```
broadcast(+, a, A)
```

Would give:

```
julia> broadcast(+, a, A)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  0.553562 + rand()  (correct)          1.73125
 1.20583  0.106970 + rand()  (different rand()) 1.13189
```

Instead of:

```
julia> broadcast(+, a, A)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  1.21839  (0.553562 + -> 0.664824)   1.73125
 1.20583  0.771802 (0.106978 + -> 0.664824)   1.13189
```

So, I thought of this **pseudo-code**:

```
broadcast(+, a=ones(1,3) => a[2]=rand(), A)
```

Formalizing:

```
broadcast(+, <anonymous-fucntion>, A)
```

**Second EDIT:**

***Rules/Constrains:***

- Rule 1: the call must be data-transparent. That is, `A` must not change state, just like when we call `f.(A)`.
- Rule 2: not creating an auxiliary variable (`a` must not exist). The only vector that must exist, before and after, the call is `A`.
- Rule 3: `f.(A)` must be anonymous; that is, you can't use define `f` as `function f(A) ... end`

Comment: Could write your matrices A out so we can understand better what you mean?

Comment: If you need further clarification, just ask again, ok? I tried to explain even more the situation.

Comment: As I know, in your case, the broadcast can only add the same rand number. You can  add different random numer through `A[:,2] += rand(2,1)`.

Comment: or `a=ones(2,3); a[:,2] = rand(2,1); a + A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the caveat that I don't know how much you really learn by setting artificial rules like this, some tidier ways are:

```
julia> A = [ 0.705942  0.553562  0.731246
             0.205833  0.106978  0.131893 ];  # as given

julia> r = 0.664824196431979;  # the one random number

julia> (A' .+ (1, r, 1))'  # no extra vector
2×3 adjoint(::Matrix{Float64}) with eltype Float64:
 1.70594  1.21839   1.73125
 1.20583  0.771802  1.13189

julia> mapslices(row -> row .+ (1, r, 1), A; dims=2)  # one line, but slow
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  1.21839   1.73125
 1.20583  0.771802  1.13189

julia> B = A .+ 1; @views B[:, 2] .+= (-1 + r); B  # fast, no extra allocations
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  1.21839   1.73125
 1.20583  0.771802  1.13189
```

I can't tell from your question whether you want one random number or two different ones. If you want two, then you can do this:

```
julia> using Random

julia> Random.seed!(1); mapslices(row -> row .+ (1, rand(), 1), A; dims=2)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  0.675436  1.73125
 1.20583  0.771383  1.13189

julia> Random.seed!(1); B = A .+ 1; @views B[:, 2] .+= (-1 .+ rand.()); B 
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.70594  0.675436  1.73125
 1.20583  0.771383  1.13189
```

Note that `(-1 .+ rand.())` isn't making a new array on the right, it's fused by `.+=` into one loop over a column of `B`. Note also that `B[:,2] .= stuff` just writes into B, but `B[:, 2] .+= stuff` means `B[:, 2] .= B[:, 2] .+ stuff` and so, without `@views`, the slice `B[:, 2]` on the right would allocate a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd like to say that the approach taken in the other answers is the most performant one. It seems like you want the entire matrix at the end, in that case for the best performance it is generally good to get data (like randomness) in big batches and to not "hide" data from the compiler (especially type information). A lot of interesting things can be achieved with higher level abstractions but since you say performance is important, let's establish a baseline:

```
function approach1(A)
    a = ones(2,3)
    @. a[:, 2] = rand()
    broadcast(+, a, A)
end
```

```
julia> A = rand(2,3)                         
 2×3 Matrix{Float64}:                         
   0.199619   0.273481  0.99254                
   0.0927839  0.179071  0.188591                                                                  julia> @btime approach1($A)                    
   65.420 ns (2 allocations: 256 bytes)         
 2×3 Matrix{Float64}:                           
  1.19962  0.968391  1.99254                    
  1.09278  1.14451   1.18859
```

With that out of the way let's try some other solutions.

If a single row with lazy elements doesn't count as an auxiliary variable this seems like a good starting point:

```
function approach2(A)                           
    a = Matrix{Function}(undef, 1, 3)
    fill!(a, ()->1.0)
    a[2] = rand
    broadcast((a,b)->a() + b, a, A)                 
end
```

We get a row `a = [()->1.0 rand ()->1.0]` and evaluate each function when the broadcast gets that element.

```
julia> @btime approach2($A)
  1.264 μs (24 allocations: 960 bytes)
```

The performance is 20 times worse, why? We've hidden type information from the compiler, it can't tell that `a()` is a `Float64` by just asserting this (changing the last row to `broadcast((a,b)->a()::Float64 + b, a, A)` increase the performance almost tenfold:

```
julia> @btime approach2($A)                   
    164.108 ns (14 allocations: 432 bytes)
```

If this is acceptable we can make it cleaner: introduce a `LazyNumber` type that keeps track of the return type, and has promote rules/operators so we can get back to `broadcast(+, ...)`. However, we are still 2-3 times slower, can we do better?

An approach that could allow us to squeeze out some more would be to represent the whole array lazily. Something like a `Fill` type,  a `LazySetItem` that applies on top of a matrix. Once again actually creating the array will be cheaper unless you can avoid getting parts of the array

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is not very clear what you are trying to achieve, and even if what you want to learn is how to achieve something or how theoretically something works.
If all you want is just to add a random vector to a matrix column (and 1 elsewhere), it is as simple as... add a random vector to the desired matrix column and 1 elsewhere:

```
julia> A = rand(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.94194   0.691855  0.583107
 0.198166  0.740017  0.914133

julia>  A[:,[1,3]] .+= 1
2×2 view(::Matrix{Float64}, :, [1, 3]) with eltype Float64:
 1.94194  1.58311
 1.19817  1.91413

julia> A[:,2] += rand(size(A,1))
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0306116987831297
 0.8757712661515558

julia> A
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.94194  1.03061   1.58311
 1.19817  0.875771  1.91413
```

Comment: The general purpose is: I want to understand how to add generic matrices, which are generated following a procedure.

You have made imperative calls to achieve the goal. I would like to do that through anonymous functions.

Rules of such call: it must be data-transparent. That is, A must not change state, just like when we call f.(A).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have  `a` be the same size as `A`, and then you don't even need broadcasting or any weird tricks:

```
julia> A = rand(2,3)
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.564824  0.765611  0.841353
 0.566965  0.322331  0.109889

julia> a = ones(2,3);

julia> a[:, 2] .= [rand() for _ in 1:size(a, 1)] #in every row, make the second column's value a different rand() result

julia> a
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  0.519228   1.0
 1.0  0.0804104  1.0

julia> A + a
2×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.56482  1.28484   1.84135
 1.56696  0.402741  1.10989
```

Comment: Because you are creating and an `a` vector, and I would like to save memory not doing that. That has to do with performance, in my case.

Rule 2: not creating an auxiliary variable. The only vector that must exist, before and after, the call is A.